# Допоможіть перекласти слово "globetrotter"

Tags: переклад, from-english

Часто бачила в інстаграмерів у біо, що вони називають себе **globetrotter**. Цікаво, як краще перекласти це слово українською?

Перекладач Гугл дає варіант [перекладу](https://translate.google.com.ua/?hl=ru#en/uk/globetrotter) **завзятий мандрівник**.

Перевірила усі значення слова **завзятий** - щодо людини це *пристрасний*, що не зовсім відповідає значенню слова в англ. мові.

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/zavzjatyj)

Словник Оксфорд дає значення слова **trotter** як *поросяча ніжка* або *кінська хода*.

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trotter)

Сайт [ReversoContext](http://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/trotter#%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%80), яким часто користуюся, дає синоніми

> courier, messenger, delivery man

тобто **trotter** це *кур'єр*.

Ну то як, **globetrotter** - *глобальний кур'єр*? чи *світовий рисак*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Йдемо за конкретним поясненням цього слова до ґуґлу, де знаходимо посилання на сайт [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/globetrotter):

> 1. a person who travels regularly or frequently to countries all over the world.
>
> First recorded in 1870-75; globe + trotter

Тобто, це не нове слово, воно з'явилося у 19 сторіччі та означає: людина, яка реґулярно чи часто їздить у різні країни по всьому світу.

Такі самі тлумачення дають [thefreedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/globetrotter), [merriam webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/globe-trotter), [oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/globetrotter) і ще купа словників.

Переклад ґуґлу в такому разі здається цілком прийнятним, "**завзятий мандрівник**" цілком відповідає англійському "travels regularly or frequently".

Гарне пояснення можна знайти також у [словнику англицизмів](http://slovopedia.org.ua/46/53395/302153.html):

> **ГЛОБТРОТЕР**  л.н.а. «завзятий мандрівник» - globe-trotter < англ. globe
>   «земна куля» і англ. trot «іти пішки».
>
> «Одна з'явилась на Хрещатику, щоб дописати свої мемуари, об'їздила весь світ, 
>   нічого не відкрила нового, топтала тисячолітні стежки пілігримів і
>   глобтротерів».  Павло Загребельний. Диво. К., 1968, с.292.
>
> «Знімок, на якому ми бачимо братів-глобтротерів, зроблений в Іспанії». 
>   Всесвіт, 1971, №12, с.150.

Тобто, в українській мові є й пряме запозичення через транслітерацію.

[@Sasha](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3686/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%96%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-globetrotter#comment6378_3688) у коментарі слушно згадав розмовне слово "[обходисвіт](http://sum.in.ua/s/obkhodysvit)":

> ОБХОДИ́СВІТ, а, чол., розм., рідко. Той, хто багато мандрує.

[@bytebuster](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3686/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%96%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-globetrotter#comment6380_3688) не менш слушно додає цитату з "Володару перснів" у перекладі Мокровольського:

«- **Обійдисвіт** – надто скромне прізвисько для тебе, сину Араторна! – із захватом вигукнув Еомер. – Я б назвав тебе **Облетисвіт**...»

Ці останні переклади навіть трохи краще підходять, аніж "завзятий мандрівник" і "глобтротер", адже в них береться до уваги слово "globe" у значенні "планета Земля", "світ" на відміну від першого перекладу, і вони утворюються від питомих українських слів - на відміну від другого.

Comment: а якщо людина завзято мандрує лише Україною?

Comment: @Yola сьогодні у загальному сприйнятті ЗАВЗЯТІСТЬ мандрівників поєднується більше з мандрами світом, тобто, уточнювати треба радше для випадку з мандрами Україною, а не світом, але я доповнив відповідь, думаю, вона тепер повніша.

Comment: а як тоді перекласти spacetrotter - той хто завзято мандрує по планетах ;) Здається треба якось прив'язуватись до нашої кульки.

Comment: Цікаво, чи підійде сюди «[затятий](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=33397&page=1070)» у значенні 2 «який виражає найвищий ступінь ознаки, вияву чого-небудь»? Чи це буде вже занадто сильний ступінь вираження ознаки?

Comment: @Sasha я, до речі, дивився словник з цією статтею і мені здалося що це слово, все-таки, не зовсім підходить.

Comment: Є вираз «громадянин світу», що, як я раніше думав, означає щось на зразок «globetrotter» — але виявилося, що це словосполучення має ще й пряме значення, яке недоречне. Може «мешканець світу» або просто «мандрівник світом»?

Comment: А ще є розмовне слово «[обходи́світ](http://sum.in.ua/s/obkhodysvit) ([-ка](http://sum.in.ua/s/obkhodysvitka))».

Comment: @Sasha обходисвіт - супер. Додам, як буду з комп'ютера.

Comment: *«- **Обійдисвіт** – надто скромне  прізвисько для  тебе, сину Араторна! – із захватом  вигукнув Еомер. –  Я б назвав тебе  **Облетисвіт**...»* — LOTR у перекладі О.М.Мокровольського

Comment: @Yola як вам? Ми достатньо прив’язались в кінцевій частині відповіді до нашої культури?

Comment: Так, +1 від мене ви маєте;)

Comment: Взагалі-то постанова Кабміну, на яку ви посилаєтесь, затверджує таблицю транслітерації українського алфавіту латиницею, а не навпаки. Проте [§ 87 Чинного правопису української мови](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par87) каже нам, що літери G та H передаються літерою Г. Збереження звуку [g] не є порушенням орфоепічної норми тільки для власних назв, про це нам каже примітка до [§15](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par15).

Таблиця ж, затверджена Кабміном, була створена для формалізації, щоб полегшити роботу, яка потребує латинізації українських слів.

Comment: @muffin так, ви праві, видаляю.

Answer (score -2):

Слово globetrotter можна перекласти як: людина, яка багато подорожує по світу . Перекладено тут: http://opentran.net/english/en-uk.html?ua

Comment: Перепрошую, Ваша відповідь була вилучена модератором, на мою думку, помилково — зараз її відновили.

Comment: Про всяк випадок хочу пояснити, чому Ваша відповідь може збирати «мінуси»:

Comment: 1. По-перше, запитувач(ка) насправді розуміє значення слова «globetrotter». Він (вона) хотів (-ла) віднайти якийсь приблизний український еквівалент (бажано одним словом), а не просто переклад. Хоча це, мабуть, його (її) помилка, що він (вона) неточно сформулював (-ла) запитання, а не Ваша (що Ви не вгадали, що він (вона) хоче).

Comment: 2. По-друге, автоматичні онлайн-перекладачі (OpenTran, Google Translate тощо) зазвичай не є надійним джерелом для пошуку перекладу слів. Вони можуть дуже спростити роботу, коли стоїть задача перекласти цілий текст (якщо людина не лінується потім відредагувати) або зрозуміти для себе приблизно значення якогось слова, але через їхні принципи роботи і способи наповнення вони часто видають помилкові варіанти, тому не є надійним джерелом. В таких випадках, мабуть, доречніше користуватися онлайн-**словниками** (що заповнюються людьми, а не автоматичне і мають окрему статтю для кожного слова).

Comment: Перепрошую за незручності і дуже радий Вашій спробі допомогти.